# How to get a String out of a String[] with startsWith

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Im trying to get a string that startsWith "O-" out of a string[] but don't know how

```js
const players = Array.from(world.getPlayers())
    for (let player of players) {
        let tags = player.getTags() // tags is the Array
        
        let tag = tags.startsWith("O-")
        
    }
```

Comment: is `tag` supposed to be an array or just one string?

Comment: tag is supposed to be the string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming `player.getTags` returns an array of strings, and you only want a single tag, you can use the `find` method, and pass to it a function that checks if a tag starts with "O-".

```js
let tag = tags.find(t => t.startsWith("O-"))
```

Comment: The find() method returns the value of the first element that passes a test. If there are multiple elements that passes the test then this code fails to return them all

Comment: The OP asked "to get a string", not strings.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `.filter` method

```
const players = Array.from(world.getPlayers())

for (let player of players) {
    let tags = player.getTags() // tags is the Array
    
    let tag = tags.filter(el => el.startsWith("O-")
    // Here 'tag' is an array of elements of 'tags' start start with 'O-'
    
}
```